# is there a goback() for webview?

Tags: android, html, webview

i am new to android so it might be a rookie question. I'm loading a local html file into a webview. The html code is linking images that are also stored in the asset dir. i cant go back to thumbnails once an image is on fullscreen. back button end the webview activity. any idea? (To all those whos downrating my question...F U)

Comment: answer is in your question title

Comment: the image goes fullscreen so when i press the "Back" button it end the activity not just the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your back button closes the activity because that's the normal behaviour. What you need to do if you want to use the back button to act as a Go back button for your WebView is:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            yourWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

For further questions, please try to use the auto-complete feature, not only shows the methods / values you can use but also displays the corresponding JavaDoc to learn how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) and especially at "goBack()"

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this tutorial on webview a little while ago. It does have a go back feature. Check it out [here](http://androidhappenings.blogspot.com/2013/01/android-app-development-101-5th.html)